# javascript - find iframe parent width

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, adsense

Busy re-configuring site to be responsive and use responsive AdSense ads with the "backup ads" option but I need the target for the backup to be able to do the following:

1. send script that will determine the width of the iframe parent.
2. use that to value to resize iframe to 100% of its direct parent(call js in parent?)
3. then call my adserver (same domain !!) with width as parameter so that MY adserver knows what size advert to send back so as not to break the layout of the page. *(use iframe src="myadserver.php?w=125" to do that)*
   I have tried everything I could think of or could find - no luck (even crashed FF 44.0.2 !!!)

But while writing this I thought of something else to worry about:
Does the AdSense script embedded on my page do the creating of the iframe or is it done by the return from the AdSense server?

If it is not the embedded scripting then this may be impossible due to the cross domain security "thing".
ANY help or suggestions would be appreciated - thanks

Comment: Jai - Thanks for the "cleanup"

Answer (score 0):

I found this very useful for recent project where I needed to know the width of content for an iFrame.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

However, I had control of both servers/domains, whereas you'll have no control over AdSense. I feel there may be a way to get it to work for you though and definitely takes out some of the headaches you might face.